# Command for toggling mono audio

Tags: windows-10, command-line, audio, mono

There is an option in Settings app under Ease of Access > Audio that allows [system-wide mono audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRfO6.png).

I find the audio sounds better on mono audio when using telecoil neckloops, however I switch between the neckloop and headphones and find it annoying that I left the mono audio on when using headphones.

Is there a command that I can create a shortcut to, and I can activate it using an automation task or manually?

Comment: If the registry option listed [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/mono-audio-windows-10) triggers instantly you could do it using the `reg` [command](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-edit-registry-using-command-prompt-windows-10) with something like: `reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio /f /t REG_DWORD /v AccessibilityMonoMixState /d 1`

Comment: The changes are reflected in the registry editor immediately after refreshing but the Settings app doesn't update even after closing and reopening it nor does the audio sound mono yet. I found that the changes properly take affect after restarting the audio service using `net start audiosrv` and `net stop audio srv`, which that is what the Settings app is probably doing whenever the switch is toggled.

Comment: So making a batch/cmd script that does all three would produce the desired outcome. Stop audiosrv, toggle reg, start audiosrv. Does the stop/start interrupt active sound streams? Does toggling it in settings interrupt them anyway?

Comment: Toggling the mono audio option in the settings interrupts the audio and resumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above comment chain, [capturing output of reg query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412150/batch-regex-the-output-of-reg-query-command-to-a-variable) and some help for my failing knowledge of batch [if/else structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file), we have the following `monoAudioToggle.cmd`:

```
@echo off

REM query audio state. 0x0: Stereo, 0x1: Mono

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio /v AccessibilityMonoMixState') do set "var=%%b"

REM stop audio service

net stop audiosrv

REM Toggle mono/stereo setting in registry

if "%var%"=="0x1" (
  reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio /f /t REG_DWORD /v AccessibilityMonoMixState /d 0
) else (
  reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio /f /t REG_DWORD /v AccessibilityMonoMixState /d 1
)

REM restart audio service

net start audiosrv
```

Comment: The script works, just the 0 and 1 values needs to be swapped as it is toggling the mono audio state not just restarting it with the same value.

Comment: this didnt work for me unfortunately, perhaps something has changed with windows 10 since this was written