# Enable mono sound with registry key in windows (10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I found a registry key that is supposed to toggle the mono audio setting in windows

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio\AccessibilityMonoMixState**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio]
"AccessibilityMonoMixState"=dword:00000000
```

source: https://www.msftnext.com/enable-mono-audio-windows-10/

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything.

If I flip this switch in settings, it changes immediately:

[image]

Any idea why this isn't working? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: [I know why but not how to fix] The button tells the OS immediately, the reg tells it next time it feels like having a look at your settings. Hopefully someone will know how to make it 'push' instead. Wish you luck :)

Comment: Did you sign in and out? The registry for such settings is loaded on sign in.

Comment: signing in and out kinda defeats the purpose, hopefully someone knows how to trigger a refresh in the settings immediately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command for toggling mono audio](https://superuser.com/questions/1480822/command-for-toggling-mono-audio)

Comment: tried that batch file but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why do you need to use the reg key? Take a step back and and describe what you're trying to do and we may be able yo find a solution that does work.

Comment: I need to switch between mono/stereo sound in a much easier way than going into the settings every time, IE setting up a hotkey that changes it.